# Arc's position on circle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I've got few pixels wide circle (circle is UIBezierPath based). I have to put an arc (which is basically UIView subclass with custom drawing) on the circle so the arc covers circle. I know how to calculate rotation of arc and position but something is not right. I mean I know the reason - it's beacause center property which is assigned to center of UIView, if it was center of the arc, everything would be great. But it's not.

I also know how to solve that. I have to calculate smaller radius where I will put arcs on. But how to do that. Basically it seems easy but because of the arc is in rectangular UIView it gets a bit harder. I'll show you some images so you can see the problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change the anchor point of each arc view's layer.  [You can read about the anchor point here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW9) if you don't already know about it.
You will need to add the QuartzCore framework to your build target and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

```
CGRect circleBounds = circleView.bounds;

topArcView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 0);
topArcView.layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleBounds), 0);

bottomArcView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 1);
bottomArcView.layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(circleBounds));

leftArcView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, .5);
leftArcView.layer.position = CGPointMake(circleBounds.origin.x, CGRectGetMidY(circleBounds));

rightArcView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, .5);
rightArcView.layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(circleBounds), CGRectGetMidY(circleBounds));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make the UIView subclass the same size and center point as the circle's rect.  Then draw the arc in the correct location.

Comment: It's not the case, every single green subview has to be subview of this circle. I have to calculate radius where I should put this arcs on, but how to calculate length of a space between green line and light gray "wheel"